# Java: Getting the char index element of a String that's stored in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, abstract-data-type

I'm new to programming and am working on a project I was hoping I could get some help with. The project specifications are as follows:

> Implement the ADT character string as the class LinkedString by using
>   a linked list of characters. Include the following LinkedString
>   constructors and methods:
>
> LinkedString(char[] value)
>
> Allocates a new character linked list so that it represents the
>   sequence of characters currently contained in the character array
>   argument.
>
> LinkedString(String original)
>
> Initializes a new character linked list so that it represents the same
>   sequence of characters as the argument.
>
> char charAt(int index)
>
> Returns the character value at the specified index.  The first
>   character in the linked character string is in position zero.
>
> LinkedString concat(LinkedString str)
>
> Concatenates the specified linked character string to the end of this
>   linked character string.
>
> boolean isEmpty()
>
> Returns true if, and only if length() is 0.
>
> int length()
>
> Returns the length of this linked character string.
>
> LinkedString substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new linked character string that is a substring of this
>   linked character string.
>
> Implement LinkedString so that it mimics the Java String class.  For
>   example, character positions should start at zero.  Also, keep track
>   of the number of characters in the string with a variable named size;
>   the length should be determined without traversing the linked list and
>   counting the nodes.  Remember to include a Test class which creates
>   one or more LinkedString objects and invokes each and every method in
>   your LinkedString ADT.

So I have three classes: the LinkedString class, the Node class, and a LinkedStringTest class that runs the main method. So far this is what I have for the LinkedString class:

```
public class LinkedString {



    private int size;  //var keeps track of number of characters

    private Node head;

    public LinkedString(){  //no argument constructor

        head = null;

        size = 0;

    }

    public LinkedString(char[] value){

        if(value.length == 0)
        return;    
            Node node = new Node(value[0]);
        head = node;
        size++;
        Node current = head;

        for(int nodeIndex = 1; nodeIndex < value.length; nodeIndex++){            
            node = new Node (value[nodeIndex]);
            current.next = node;
            size++;
        }

    }

    public LinkedString(String original){

        if(original.length() == 0)
            return;
                Node node = new Node(original.charAt(0));
                head = node;
                size++;
                Node current = head;    

        for(int nodeIndex = 1; nodeIndex < original.length(); nodeIndex++){
                node = new Node(original.charAt(nodeIndex));
                current.next = node;
                current = current.next;
                size++;

            }
    }


    public char charAt(int index){

        Node current = head;
        for(int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < size; nodeIndex++){
        if(nodeIndex == index){
            return current.item;}
        else{
            current = current.next;

        }
        }   
    }


    public LinkedString concat(LinkedString str){

        if(str.head == null){
            return this;
        }
        else if(head == null){
            size = str.length();
            return str;
        }
        else{
            Node current = head;
        while(current.next != null)
            current = current.next;
                current.next = str.head;
            size += str.length();
            return this;
        }

    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return length() == 0;     

    }

    public int length(){

        return size;
    }

    public LinkedString substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex){

        String substr = " ";

        for(int nodeIndex = beginIndex; nodeIndex <= endIndex; nodeIndex++)
            substr += charAt(nodeIndex);
        LinkedString linkedSubstring = new LinkedString(substr);
        return linkedSubstring;
    }
}
```

This is my node class:

```
public class Node {
    char item;
    Node next;       

    public Node() {
        setItem(' ');
        setNext(null);
    }
    public Node(char newItem) {
        setItem(newItem);
        setNext(null);
    }
    public Node(char newItem, Node newNext) {
        setItem(newItem);
        setNext(newNext);
    }
    public Node(Node newNext) {
        setItem(' ');
        setNext(newNext);
    }
    public void setItem(char newItem) {
        item = newItem;
    }
    public void setNext(Node newNext) {
        next = newNext;
    }
    public char getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

And this is my LinkedStringTest class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 


public class LinkedStringTest {



    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] chars = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
        LinkedString list1 = new LinkedString(chars);
        System.out.print("The original string is ");
        System.out.println(chars);
        System.out.println("Is the list empty? " + list1.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("The characters length: " + list1.length());
        System.out.println("Enter the position of a character and press Enter: ");
        int pos1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The character at position " + pos1 + " is " + list1.charAt(pos1));
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String strng1 = sc.next();
        LinkedString list2 = new LinkedString(strng1);
        System.out.println("The string is " + list2);
        System.out.println("That string concatanated with the original string is " + list1.concat(list2));
        System.out.println("Enter the starting and ending index of part of a string ");
        int start = sc.nextInt();
        int end = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The substring from " + start + " to " + end + " is " + list1.substring(start,end));

    }

}
```

This is the output I get when I run the test class:

```
run:
The original string is project2.LinkedString@55f96302
Hello
Is the list empty? false

The characters length: 5

Enter the position of a character and press Enter: 

2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement
    at project2.LinkedString.charAt(LinkedString.java:64)
    at project2.LinkedStringTest.main(LinkedStringTest.java:28)
C:\Users\Im\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 47 seconds)
```

As you can see, when I enter an index position (in this case the number 2) I get error messages. The first error (line 64) is at the start of my charAt method. The second error (line 28) is in the main method where I try to send the integer (in this case number 2) to the charAt method.

What am doing wrong with my charAt() method that makes it so that it cannot return the char at the requested index position?
Also, why when I tried to print out the object list1 near the beginning of the main method did I only get the reference address instead of the value itself?

```
    System.out.print("The original string is " + list1);
    System.out.println(chars);
```

I know I have lots of problems with this program, and I thank you in advance for any help you may be able to give me.

Comment: The "first error" (line 64) is self-explanatory: your `charAt` method does not compile as it has code-paths that do not lead to a return statement, but the method is declared to return a `char`. Consider this: what happens if the `index` argument assumes a value that is either negative or equal-to-or-greater-than `size`? In that case you'll never reach a return statement. Note that there really is only _one_ error in the provided output as it is a stack-trace. Overly simplified, it tells you what sequence of calls lead to the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Problem - Missing return statement.

In charAt method, return statement is inside an if condition of a for loop. This means that in the for loop, there will be times when program control will in "else". so, java is getting confused thinking that there is no return statement. one possible solution is as below which will fix the issue.

```
public char charAt(int index){

    Node current = head;
    for(int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < size; nodeIndex++){
        if(nodeIndex == index) {
            break;
        }
        else{
            current = current.next;

        }
    }

    return current.item;

}
```

2. After the above change, if you run the code, you will get NullPointerException. reason is there is a subtle bug LinkedString constructor. Fix is as below - Add line current.next = node.

   public LinkedString(char[] value){

   ```
       if(value.length == 0)
           return;
       Node node = new Node(value[0]);
       head = node;
       size++;
       Node current = head;

       for(int nodeIndex = 1; nodeIndex < value.length; nodeIndex++){
           node = new Node (value[nodeIndex]);
           current.next = node;
           current = node;
           size++;
       }

   }
   ```
3. printing "list1" prints the reference and not the actual value. Solution is to override toString() method and provide a custom implementation as below:
   Note that if you print any standard object in java, it calls its default toString() method which only prints a reference (mostly). by overriding toString method, we can pass the string that we want java to print.

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       char value[];
       value = new char[size];
       Node n = head;

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       value[i] = n.item;
       n = n.next;
   }

   String str = String.copyValueOf(value);
   return str;
   ```

   }